# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre sobreescribir un método y crear un método que haga lo mismo?

Tags: java

El método *equals()* de la clase *Object* compara si dos objectos son iguales.

En el siguiente ejemplo se sobreescribio dicho método para que compare el ISBN (es como el DNI/cédula de identifiación de un libro) ya que por motivos del ejercicio teniamos que saber si dos objetos son iguales a comparando el isbn.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    if(obj instanceof Libro) {

        Libro otro=(Libro)obj;

        if(this.ISBN==otro.ISBN) {

            return true;
        }

        else {

            return false;
        }
    }

    else {

        return false;
    }
}
```

¿No es más fácil crear una método *comparaISBN()* a tener que buscar por la API un método que sobreescribir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno respecto al código que muestras la diferencia es la siguiente:

Cualquier clase que tu crees será una extensión de la clase Object entonces los métodos que tiene la clase Object serán heredados. 
En Java es imprescindible sobrescribir los métodos hashCode() y equals(Object obj) para poder identifica la relación de cada instancia de clase creada de acuerdo a las propiedades que consideres convenientes. 
Entonces si bien puedes crearte un método que comparar(Object obj) que puede ser para tu uso específico pero por ejemplo para un Set que no admite duplicados entonces si tu sobrescribe el método equals entonces cuando sean agregados valores a  un HashSet por ejemplo verificará cualquier Objeto en base al método equals.
Permitime saber si te aclaré tus dudas.

Comment: Sobreescribir estos métodos no es imprecindible. Dependiendo de como se use la clase puede no hacer falta, puede ser conveniente, o puede ser necesario.

Comment: No leíste bien mi respuesta, dice en Java es imprescindible los métodos..... para poder identificar la relación de cada instancia de clase creada.  Lee de nuevo y entende el contexto, @Juan  saludos.

Comment: Si en el sistema hay solo una instancia de cada libro, para saber si dos variables apuntan al mismo libro no necesito sobrescribir ningún método. Y lo de leer de nuevo estaba de más...

Comment: Ok, cuando te refieres a una instancia supongo que es un objeto pero no te entiendo de cada libro? libro lo veo como una clase. Entonces tu referencia es que va haber claseA, claseB, claseC,.. De cada clase una instancia? No entiendo a que te refieres.

Comment: Libro es la clase. "Objeto de una clase" e "instancia de una clase" se usan indistintamente para describir lo mismo.  De la clase libro podría crear 2 o más instancias con el mismo ISBN, pero no, por como pensé el sistema decido que solo habrá una instancia de esta clase para cada ISBN. Bajo estas condiciones, si tengo una variable libroEnStock y otra libroBuscado, puedo hacer libroEnStock.equals(libroBuscado) sin tener que sobreescribir equals() y lo mismo con hashCode() porque esto evaluará a true cuando ambas variables referencien la misma instancia unicamente.

Comment: Si, pero no creo que tu caso sea válido, porque únicamente saldrá true del método equals cuando hagas algo como Libro libroEnStock = new Libro("123"); Libro libroBuscado = libroEnStock;. Sino siempre tiene. Dará falso si no sobrescribes el equals. Algo como Libro libroEnStock = new Libro("123"); Libro libroBuscado = New Libro("123"); esto te dará false siempre. Si tu no sobrescribes el equals.